# useState setter as context api values

Tags: reactjs, memoization, react-context

I have a state inside a functional component
const [counts, setCounts] = useState({});

I also have a nested components structure which is wrapped around a context and counts and setCounts are being passed as context value.

I read that when we pass functions, arrays or objects inside the react context, referential checks don't pass and child components re-render even if the values havent changed. I tried memoizing the direct child component to stop the re-rendering of child components, but have been unsuccessful.

Anyone can suggest the correct way how I can memoize the context values **counts and setcounts** and pass them to the context so that re-render cycles don't happen.